# How to not receive the GNU notification every first time I run screen

Tags: macos, terminal, gnu-screen

I have been an avid user of the "screen" command for a long time now and suddenly I seem to have a problem getting it to work.

Every first time I start screen in a new terminal session I get this message:

```
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Copyright (c) 1993-2002 Juergen Weigert, Michael Schroeder
Copyright (c) 1987 Oliver Laumann

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2, or (at your option) any
later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public
License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program (see the file COPYING); if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA
 02111-1307, USA.

Send bugreports, fixes, enhancements, t-shirts, money, beer & pizza to screen@uni-erlangen.de
```

as I use the screen command in a shell script (background) it does not work anymore.

Can anyone tell my how to either acknowledge this message so not to see it anymore or how to disable it?
I've been searching for an answer but have not found it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just use `screen -q` ?

Comment: Not really but when combined with detached mode e.g. `screen -q -dmS tunnel ssh sometunnel` it does not work?!

Comment: the `-d` option will suppress printing of error messages but the copyright notice is not actually an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was `screen -q <rest of command here>`